# How to submit an HTML form, process with ajax, and display PHP variable in DIV on same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I've been reluctant to open a question, but after fighting this for 6+ hours I'm now cross-eyed. 
I've got some experience with PHP and HTML but Ajax and jQuery is new to me (I first heard about it yesterday).

I want the page to display the submitted values inside the div class="result" without refreshing. Anyway, the workflow:

j.php loads > user fills out two text fields (phone and gz) > click Submit button > jpost.php is called and echos variables > PHP variables need to display is div class=result on j.php

j.php =

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> <!-- load jquery via CDN -->
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {//start document ready
      $('#submit-button').click(function (){
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'jpost.php',
        data: $("#cdr").serialize(),
success: function(d){
   $(".result").html(d);
}
    });
  });
 });//end document ready
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="cdr">
 <div>  
   <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" value="" placeholder="phone" size="40" />
 </div>
 <div> 
  <input type="text" id="gz" name="gz" value="" placeholder="gz" size="40" />
 </div>
 <div>
   <button id="submit-button">Submit</button>
 </div>
</div>
   <div class="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

jpost.php

```
<?php
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $gz = $_POST['gz'];
echo $phone;
echo $gz;
print_r($_POST);
  echo "grrrr"
?>
```

So all I want is $gz and $phone to echo out in my result div on j.php, but all that shows up is: 
Array ( ) grrrr

This makes me believe that my variables are being lost somewhere :P or I'm echoing them incorrectly.

Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: it means that there is no data sent . are you sure you completed the form and then submitted ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short**

The problem was :

1.You need a form in order to serialise the data ( and not a div ) 2. You need to prevent the default behaviour of the event

**Long**
In order to serialise the data, you need to have a form. i created the form with id `#cdr-form`
Also, you need to make sure to prevent the default behaviour of the button ( event ) with `e.preventDefault()` . [Read more about it here](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> <!-- load jquery via CDN -->
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {//start document ready
      $('#submit-button').click(function (e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost/~metaly/tests/j.php',
        data: $("#cdr-form").serialize(),
success: function(d){
   $(".result").html(d);
}
    });
  });
 });//end document ready
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="cdr">
<form id="cdr-form">
 <div>  
   <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" value="" placeholder="phone" size="40" />
 </div>
 <div> 
  <input type="text" id="gz" name="gz" value="" placeholder="gz" size="40" />
 </div>
 <div>
   <button id="submit-button">Submit</button>
 </div>
 </form>
</div>
   <div class="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fixup ! Sorry, i was tired.